# By what mechanism do cephalopods regrow limbs?

Tags: zoology, physiology, marine-biology, invertebrates, regeneration

As far as I can tell, there are two types of limb regeneration: epimorphosis and morphallaxis. Epimorphosis is used by animals such as amphibians and various phyla of worms, while morphallaxis is used by hydras.

I have been trying to find out which of these mechanisms is used by cephalopods, and no reliable source paints a clear picture one way or the other. Can anyone here help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well gastropod mollusks use Epimorphosis, so it is likely cephalopods use the same mechanisms. Basically all triploblastic organisms use this mechanism so phylogenic bracketing points towards it as well.

morphallaxis is generally restricted to very simple organisms.

[Regeneration of the visual system in gastropods (Mollusca)
Oksana Tuchina  Victor Benno Meyer‐Rochow](https://www.jstor.org/stable/40663842?seq=1)

[Neural regeneration in gastropod molluscs
Author links open overlay panelStacia B.Moffett](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030100829580014Y)

[Regeneration of the visual system in gastropods (Mollusca)
Oksana Tuchina  Victor Benno Meyer‐Rochow (alternative link)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1744-7410.2010.00195.x)